# Is it possible to disable shadows on all components?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I was wondering if it is possible to disable shadows/elevation on all components through some configuration?

Comment: `.component * { box-shadow: none; }` ?? ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean box-shadow?

You can use * to set value of a propert for all elements.

This should work in your case:

```
*{
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

!important will overrite all settings to a property

You may or may not need !important. Depends on your other CSS settings regarding box-shadow

Comment: My goal is to do it trough configuration of Quasar. Overriding the applied css is not the best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This link describes how to customize any Quasar SASS/SCSS/Styl variable (Shadows are defined as variables too).

`https://quasar.dev/style/sass-scss-variables`

In essence, there are Quasar variables $shadow-0 through $shadow-24 and $shadow-up-0 through $shadow-up-24 that you can override individually. Else you might find it easier to override

```
$elevation-umbra
$elevation-penumbra
$elevation-ambient
```

to make them fully transparent, so that the shadows, even though present are not visible.